# Why mine while block isn't running? (Python 3.x)

Tags: python-3.x, while-loop

I was making a pretty simple game of rolling dice simulator, but the while block isn't running, don't know why!

```
if data == 'roll the dice':
    print("You've got", str(rn) + "!")

    while repeat == False:
        rn2 = random.randint(1,6)
        data2 = input('Do you want to roll again? (Y/N): ').lower()

        if data2 == 'y':
            print("You've got", rn2, "this time!")
            repeat=True
        if data2 == 'n':
            print('Thanks for playing!')
            repeat=False
```

Comment: Why are you looping while `repeat == False` anyway? Shouldn't it be `repeat == True`? (NB this is equivalent to `repeat`).

Answer (score 0):

Initialize the value of `repeat` to be equal to `False`

Answer (score 0):

You don’t ever initialize repeat? This won’t even run once

Comment: The part where I defined repeat isn't mentioned here! But thanks I've sort it out.